# I need help understanding this function with counter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

Trying to figure out what this function does, can somone explain it to me. is there a better platform for these questions?

```
function whatDoIDoFunction (x, arr) {
   var y = 0;
   var i=0;

  for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] == x)
      y++;
  }
return y;
}
```

Comment: it counts specific items of the array.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand? If you do not understand what the function is doing you probably don't understand syntax/operations it uses. Which ones are you not familiar with?

Comment: Good Variable names are the key to readable code. `x` should rather be `value` or `searchFor`, `y` should be `count` and `whatDoIDo` should be `countOccurences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good to add `console.logs` to see what's happening.

```js
function whatDoIDoFunction(x, arr) {
  var y = 0;
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('examining ' + arr[i]);
    if (arr[i] == x)
      y++;
    console.log('y is ' + y);
  }
  return y;
}

var array = [1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1,0]
whatDoIDoFunction(1, array);
```

If you run the snippet, you will observe that `y` increments only when the "current" array element is equal to the `x` that is passed in as the first parameter. In other words, your function counts how many occurrences of `x` are in `arr`.